# .htaccess - need to 301 a URL with special characters

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, special-characters, http-status-code-301

I have a long URL from an legacy website which I need to 301, example: domain.com/web/vehicle/655520/2007-Hummer-H2---?sort_by=year&args=All_years--All_makes--All_models--All_body_types--All_vehicles

I need to redirect this (and many more similar urls) to a new page on a redesigned website, page example: domain.com/hummer.php

How do you strip the special characters (ex. ---?) and everything else from the URL so that I can successfully use a 301?

Answer (score 0):

You  can't "strip" anything with mod_rewrite.
You can only create references from parts of a string and use them for building the new url.

How you can do it depends on what url you like to build out of the original url.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to? Unless you're planning to code a long, long list of redirects into your .htaccess file, you should be doing all of your redirects in PHP.

From the URL example you gave, I assume all items have a unique ID that is tied to the URL already. In that case, you could create a map in your database that says that the "proper" URL for item 655520 is hummer.php. You can use that to perform a redirect from PHP.

Here's an example of how you can do this. I'm making the assumption that you already have an .htaccess file which translates the URL into a GET. Something like `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?request=$1 [L,QSA]`

```
//determine if you were passed a "legacy URL" (not shown)
if (legacyURL) {
  $urlComponents = $explode("/", $_GET['request']);
  $url = getItemUrl($components[2]);
  header("Location: " . $url,TRUE,301);
  exit();
}
```